# Make Dynamic sheet and range selection Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, dynamic

I have a spreadsheet that ends up producing a range on one of mant sheets as a PDF.
There are four possible sheets to select and four ranges for each sheet depending on how many pages need to be PDF'ed. Currently I have a code with some 16 separate selections depending on a value found in cell xCell.

Sheet and range selection relies on 3 things: How many heats are going to be run (3 or 5); the racing format  (regular or handicap); and the number of races being run in a day (6,8,10,12,14 etc). Number of heats and format are used to select the sheet while the number of races selects the range (width and length of document).

I've some code that allows me to show the relevant address in a cell

```
If HEATS = 5 And HC_REG = "Regular" And TeamRaces < 7 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Race Meeting Information").Range("DZ1") = "Sheets(" & "C2 - 5 Heat Team Sheet" & ").Range(" & "B2:AL61" & ")"
End If

If HEATS = 5 And HC_REG = "Regular" And TeamRaces > 6 < 13 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Race Meeting Information").Range("DZ1") = "Sheets(" & "C2 - 5 Heat Team Sheet" & ").Range(" & "B2:AL61,B67:AL126" & ")"
```

How do I use the address in DZ1 with the code that produces the PDF??

I've tried the following (and several other iterations) but no success.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Race Meeting Information").Range("DZ1").Value.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

HELP!!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat` function.

```
Sub btnExportPDF_Click()

Dim dz1Range As Range
Dim saveLocation As String

saveLocation = "C:\Users\[user]\Downloads\myPDFFile.pdf"
Set dz1Range = Range("A1:A9")

Sheets("Race_Meeting_Information").Range(dz1Range.Address).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DanielvL I've tried the code but it faults at `Sheets("Race_Meeting_Information").Range(dz1Range.Address).Select` with "Script out of range. What does the line `Set dz1Range = Range("A1:A9")` do please?

Comment: It's OK. Looked at it in a different light and now understand! Thanks

Comment: No problem, could you mark it as solution if so?